# Create TCP Adapters Spring integration 4

Tags: spring-integration

Is it possible to receive data stream from remote host and port using spring integration TCP adapters? 
If yes, how do I create it dynamic TCP adapter on spring 4 & spring java DSL?

Answer (score 0):

The `<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter>` is backed by the `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter`. So you should configure `@Bean` for that as well as `@Bean` for the `TcpNetClientConnectionFactory`.

If you want use that from the Spring Integration Java DSL , you can simply start your `IntegrationFlow` using appropriate factory method:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow tcpFlow() {
   return IntegrationFlows.from(myTcpAdapter())
         .....
         get();
}
```

Right, there is no yet DSL for IP components, so feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT) ticket on the matter and we'll take care of that for the `1.1` release.

Comment: Do not post your code in another answer; edit your question instead. TCP is a stream - you need some way to delimit messages from the stream. The `Default(De|S)erializer` uses java serialization. You need to configure an appropriate (de)serializer based on your message. You can read about the [supplied (de)serializers here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#connection-factories). If there is not one that meets your needs, you will need to provide a custom implementation. If you omit it from your configuration, a `ByteArrayCrLfSerializer` is used.

Comment: Sorry for posting the code into answer section. Thanks Gary. It worked.  the scenario is, PBX has been configured to push data stream on two different IP:port let's say 'X:port' & 'Y:port'. Now I am deploying the app on 'X' machine & listening to port so I am able to receive the stream. What shall I do to receive the data stream from 'Y:port' from machine 'X' ?

Comment: Do I need to write my own (de)serializer because for one single record I am receiving two byte stream like below: Stream 1: B 021        T00500101 DN5201    03/16 14:14:24 Stream 2:  &7030751585XXXXXXX                    5201XXX. Combining 1 & 2, which is my one single record.

Comment: Looks like a separate SO question.

Comment: Sure. I will post as separate question. In past i have followed the approach from Gary in integration samples (dynamic-ftp) to create adapters  dynamically based on configuration provided by user. So to create tcp inbound adapters based on configuration shall I follow the same approach or with Spring 4 we can achieve the same thing in different way?

Comment: I'd say it depends on the task. Different goals may be achieved different ways. Feel free to ask more questions on SO. We are always here to track SI questions.

Comment: Shall I add this one as separate question? "the scenario is, PBX has been configured to push data stream on two different IP:port let's say 'X:port' & 'Y:port'. Now I am deploying the app on 'X' machine & listening to port so I am able to receive the stream. What shall I do to receive the data stream from 'Y:port' from machine 'X' ? "

Comment: Yes, of course, you can. Please, share as much info there as you can. Including configs would be good, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73165/discussion-between-user2279564-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: what can be major reason to get IOException : socket closed during message assembly. I tried with ByteArrayRawSerialize still didn't work. I see some text in non-human readable format.